# Вводить размерность структуры с клавиатуры, а не через константу

Tags: c++, массивы, структуры

Приветствую.

Есть задание:
Создать структуру STUDENT, которая имеет поля:

1. NAME. ФИО.
2. GROUP - номер группы.
3. SES - оценки с 5 предметов. (Массив с 5 элементов).

Написать следующую программу, которая реализует действия разными функциями:

1. Возможность ввести с клавиатуры данные в массив STUD, который состоит из N переменных типа STUDENT.
2. Сортировка записей по возрастанию значений поля GROUP.

**Нужно сделать так, чтобы можно было вручную вводить количество записей в структуре, а не с помощью const n = 5.**

```
    #include<iostream>
    #include<clocale>
    using namespace std;
    int const n = 5;

    int main(){
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "Russian");

    struct student{
        char fio[20];
        int number;
        float usp[5];
    };

    student N[n];

    for(int i=0;i<n;++i){
        cout << "Введите ФИО студента  " << i << "-ого по списку: " << endl;
        cin >> N[i].fio;
        cout << "Номер группы студента " << i <<"-ого по списку: " << endl;
        if(i==0) cin >> N[i].number;
        else cin >> N[i].number;
        cout << "Введите оценки студента  " << i << "-ого по списку с пяти предметов: "<< endl;
        if(i==0){
            for(int j=0;j<n;++j){
                cout << "Предмет["<<j<<"]:";
                cin >> N[i].usp[j];
                if(N[i].usp[j]>0 && N[i].usp[j]<=5) continue;
                else {
                    --j;
                    cout << "Не больше 5!" << endl;
                }
            }
        } else for(int j=0;j<n;++j){
            cout << "Предмет["<< j <<"]:";
            cin >> N[i].usp[j];
            if(N[i].usp[j]>0 && N[i].usp[j]<=5)continue;
            else {
                --j;cout<<"Не больше 5!"<<endl;
            }
        }
    }

    cout << endl;

    cout<<"Выведение данных о студентах по возрастанию номера группы: "<<endl;
    for(int i=0;i<n-1;++i){
        int imin = i;
        for(int j=i+1;j<n;++j)
        if(N[j].number<N[imin].number) imin=j;
        float temp=N[i].number; 
        N[i].number=N[imin].number;
        N[imin].number=temp;
    }

    cout << endl;

    for(int i=0;i<n;++i){
        cout<< " " << endl;
        cout<<"ФИО студента:"<<N[i].fio<<endl;
        cout<<"Номер группы студента:"<<N[i].number<<endl;
        cout<<"Оценки студента:  "<<N[i].fio<<":"<<endl;
        for(int j=0;j<n;++j)
        cout<<"Предмет["<<j<<"]:"<<N[i].usp[j]<<endl;
    }

    return 0;
    }
```

Comment: Поскольку современные компиляторы поддерживают [VLA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable-length_array), то вполне  можете просто написать `int n; cin >>n; student N[n]; ...`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для этого нужно динамическое выделение памяти:

```
int main {
    int n;
    std::cin >> n;
    student *N = new student[n];
}
```

Создание динамического массива в С++ используется оператор [new[]](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/new/operator%20new[]/). Про него есть даже на [википедии](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/New_(C%2B%2B)).
  Только после того, как объект перестал быть нужен, правильно освобождать память вызывая `delete[]`:

```
delete[] N;
```

Comment: Хорошо, теперь как сделать так, чтобы оценок было 5? Потому что теперь в программе сравниваются значения с 5. Даже float usp[5]; не помогает. Пробовал в циклах там, где n поменять на 5, но это было не совсем правильно.

Comment: @Hinc пока не совсем понял. Но не нужно сравнивать тяжелое с горячим: `for(int j=0;j<n;++j){
                cout << "Предмет["<<j<<"]:";`. У вас `n` -- количество людей. А вы с ним сравниваете номера предметов. Это не лучшая практика. Введите для количества предметов отдельную переменную.

Answer (score 2):

Используй Динамические массивы.(Нужно знать указатели.Вот [Ссылка](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gbmsuiBk_6I)). Решение вот:`

```
cout<<"Введіть кількість студентів\n";
short kst;
cin>>kst;
student *sMas=new student[kst];//student *N=new student[kst];
//когда программа отработает, удали память при помощи delete[]
delete[]N;`
```

Comment: "Отличное" название для переменной, характеризующей динамический массив - `N`

Comment: Ща все поправимо)